# Select check box and click on download button selected image download and also download all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when user check the checkbox and click on download button  selected checkbox image will download this code I will try but  image not download

```js
function downloadSelected() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    window.open($(this).val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="/download1.jpg" />
        Download Image 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="/download2.jpg" />
        Download Image 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="/download3.jpg" />
        Download Image 3
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" onclick="downloadSelected();">Download</a>
```

this code i will try but its not work image will not download

how can  i donwload the images which chechk box are selected is there other way to download image solution

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is the mixup of javascript and jquery one way of doing it with jquery properly is to check on click which checkbox is checked and then proceed to download, Following is the way I have done it

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="/download1.jpg" />
    Download Image 1
        </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="/download2.png" />
    Download Image 2
        </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="/download3.jpg" />
    Download Image 3
        </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Download</a>
          <script>
          $(function(){
            $("a").click(function() {
            $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                window.open($(this).val());
            }
            })
          })
        })
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you  sir this is work but I have one problem when i click on download button image will not download but it will open into new windows 
so how can I use the checkbox value and then use into download button and download the image